# Juju "RegionOne" does not allow access to all required services

Tags: juju, openstack

Hi i am trying to configure juju over openstack under Ubuntu. Successfully configure the basic authentication stuff on juju enviroment.yalm but when i try to bootstrap juju this errors stop me. Anyone can give me a tip ?

Error

```
ERROR failed to GET object provider-state from container juju-ed085dd894094e7997f2e285ed52ca28
caused by: cannot create service URLs
caused by: the configured region "RegionOne" does not allow access to all required services, namely: compute, object-store
access to these services is missing: object-store
```

Config

```
 openstack:
    type: openstack
    admin-secret: xxxx
    control-bucket: juju-ed085dd894094e7997f2e285ed52ca28
    auth-url: http://xxxx.11:5000/v2.0
    auth-mode: userpass
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
    tenant-name: admin
    region: RegionOne
```

Answer (score 1):

Your openstack cloud needs to make swift available, so that juju can use it for object storage.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer !! Any tip to make it wit available ?